# How do I allow this script to work properly?

Tags: python, command, discord.py

so I type taxcalc (amount) but it wont work. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. The command is supposed to show the tax calculation by 8 percent of the given amount, but the bot just will not respond to the command. I am wondering if I am configuring the bot wrong but it could also be the code that is wrong.

````py
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def taxcalc(ctx, x: str):
        x = CHECK_M_K(str(x))
        lost = x*0.08
        lost2 = x*0.033045
        plus = round(x + x*0.12)
        plost = int(plus-lost2)
        print("plus: "+str(plus))
        print("plus lost: " + str(plost))
        for i in range(int(plus-lost2), plus):
            if x > int(1e12):
                await ctx.channel.send("***IMPOSSIBLE! You definitely DO NOT have more than 1 trillion!!***")
                break
            temp = i
            lost = i-x
            lost = "{:,}".format(lost)
            i -= round(i*0.08)
            if (i == x):
                x = temp
                x = "{:,}".format(x)
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Tax Calculator", description="Amount expected to pay: `⏣ "+ x + "`\n" + "Amount lost by tax: `⏣ "+lost+"`\n" + "Tax rate: 8%", color=0xace1af)
                await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
                print(x)
                break
            elif x == 20:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Tax Calculator", description="Amount expected to pay: `⏣ "+ str(x+2) + "`\n" + "Amount lost by tax: `⏣ 2`\n" + "Tax rate: 8%", color=0xace1af)
                await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
                print(x)
                break
            elif x > 6 and x < 19:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Tax Calculator", description="Amount expected to pay: `⏣ "+ str(x+1) + "`\n" + "Amount lost by tax: `⏣ 1`\n" + "Tax rate: `8%`", color=0xace1af)
                await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
                print(x)
                break
            elif x <= 6:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Tax Calculator", description="Amount expected to pay: `⏣ "+ str(x) + "`\n" + "Amount lost by tax: `⏣ 0`\n" + "Tax rate: `8%`", color=0xace1af)
                await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
                print(x)
                break
            else: 
                i = 0 

client.run(token removed lul)```
````

Comment: Why are you considering `x` as `str()` and then multiplying it? You can't multiply `str` with `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the data type specification.

#### What is the error?

1. You are using `Commands API` and thus you can't use `Client` Object as it not made for this. When you try to make commands then you need to use `Bot` objects of the `Commands API`. Otherwise the bot will not work but just go online.
2. You are making a `command`, and then making it an `event`. You have made a command which can be used by the user, so is not an `event` but it is an `command()`. So you are basically using `Commands API` of the library.
3. You are first saying that the `x` in the function is a string and then multiplying it with a number. You can not multiply a string with int. Due to the library discord.py the error will not be visible except the library errors. So you can't see the basic errors. You need to pay attention to what you do in the script.

#### How to fix it?

1. The first error is due the declaration of the bot as:

```
discord.Client
```

**REMOVE THIS LINE**

This is not made for the `Commands API` whereas it is made for `event`s. You need to use the commands declaration for that.

(i) Import the library like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

(ii) Declare the bot like:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
```

Now you will be able to use your commands like: `!taxcalc <value>`. This will specifically let you use the commands.

2. The second error is due to the `event` discriminator. It is a `command()` so you need to change it.

You need to change the code from:

```
@client.event
```

to:

```
@client.command()
```

3. Your argument in the function is an string (str) and then you are trying to use Mathematical Operations on it. You can not use Math Ops on any string type.

To fix it, you need to change two lines.

(i) The first line:

```
async def taxcalc(ctx, x: str):
```

Change it to:

```
async def taxcalc(ctx, x: int):
```

(ii) The second line:

```
x = CHECK_M_K(str(x))
```

Change it to:

```
x = CHECK_M_K(x)
```

---

If you do all of the changes as mentioned above, then your code would be fixed and your bot will run correctly. If you get any issues, please do ask them in the comments. :)

Thank You! :D

Comment: Here is the link to the document bc it doesnt let me type the error in comments: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wrOj4b8jRQ2RYikhjAPg0V_wP8MxX-NpVAJuKMjsrFU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You used a function: `CHECK_M_K()` in your code. Didn't you define it? Else do one thing: Remove this line from the function: `x = CHECK_M_K(x)`

Comment: New error: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wrOj4b8jRQ2RYikhjAPg0V_wP8MxX-NpVAJuKMjsrFU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay the way you wrote the color, it is not how the library understands it. Mate, your code have a lot and lot of errors. Change this: 
`embed = discord.Embed(title="Tax Calculator", description="Amount expected to pay: \`⏣ "+ x + "\`\n" + "Amount lost by tax: \`⏣ "+lost+"\`\n" + "Tax rate: 8%", color=ffb6c1)` 

to 

`embed = discord.Embed(title="Tax Calculator", description="Amount expected to pay: \`⏣ "+ x + "\`\n" + "Amount lost by tax: \`⏣ "+lost+"\`\n" + "Tax rate: 8%", color=0xffb6c1)`

Comment: @HELP You're welcome! Accept the answer if you got your answer.